# MFC check box GetCheck() bool returns unpredictably with seemingly same properties despite button clicks

Tags: mfc

I am new to MFC and   cannot figure out why I have created 2 check boxes that have from what I can tell the same properties but only one will return true upon being clicked.
Below is the code snips that show what I have but as I dig into the afx stuff where the GetCheck comes from I cannot really tell how it is implementing the checking. How does it check for a check box or is there a setting maybe that  I am missing not listed below that will cause this type of behavior. During debug I have validated the the program does enter the OnBnClicked1 and 2 once the check boxes are clicked and it calls the. GetCheck() but for 1 it always returns false and true for 2.

```
void Dialoge1Dlg::OnBnCLickedChkBox1()
{
  bool check = mctrlChkbox1.GetCheck(); //always comes back false even after checked
 // more stufff 
}

void Dialoge1Dlg::OnBnCLickedChkBox2()
{
  bool check = mctrlChkbox2.GetCheck(); //always comes back true after checked
 // more stufff 
}

//over in the .h file 
CButtom mCtrlChkbox1;
CButtom mCtrlChkbox2;
```

properties : Auto    true  //I have only listed the true properties to shorten the list all
Visible true  // others are set to false
Tabstop true

BN_CLICKED : OnBnCLickedChkBox1
BN_CLICKED : OnBnCLickedChkBox2

Comment: You won't find checkbox logic in MFC. It's not there. Not at all. Nothing. That is implemented in the Windows [Common Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/common-controls-intro). MFC just provides a **complex** wrapper. You aren't going to understand the OS nor MFC, unless you start by learning about the OS first. Ditch MFC, optionally ditch C++ in favor of C, and adventure into the Windows API.

Comment: well  I agree except  I have to use MFC unfortunately, but the Windows API sounds like a good place to start investigating so thanks for the tip

Comment: Did you hook the control `CButton`s using the Wizard or are you doing this by hand?  You have to have code in overrided `DoDataExchange` method of your dialog between the control ID that is hooked to a button type control to your control variable (e.g. mCtrlChkbox1), something like `DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_SHOW_NEW_CHECK, m_btnShowNew);`

Comment: Are you using DDX? May be you need to `UpdateData(TRUE)` before using `mVar.GetCheck()` to pass the info from the control to the variables. But as @IInspectable said you need to deepen your knowledge about MFC.

Comment: I find the suggestion to have you using C with the bare win32 api a bit too radical. Also, you seem to use control-based DDX variables (as opposed to value-based ones), so `UpdateData()` should be no issue here as sergiol suggested. If you right-click on each control in the dialog designer view and select 'Properties', do you see differences between the two controls (except for name, caption, and ID)? If not, compare the DDX_ calls in `DoDataExchange()`. There must be a difference somewhere, even as MFC is just a wrapper.

Comment: We can't see that you set up your controls right or anything like that. Have you tried using the API `IsDlgButtonChecked()` ? Does it give back the same results as the other?

Comment: Gotcha ok thanks guys I found the problem my IDC  was miss spelled in the DDX_Control function and now its is not failing the assert. thanks for the help, I previously did not really understand what that function was doing so thanks.